# Uploading image and form to database

Tags: php, database, upload, submit

So, i've been wondering for this script and still can't get it right. For some reason it won't save to my database. Any ideas why it's not working? Would appreciate any help. Thanks! Here's my script.

```html
 <?php 

 include_once ("database.php"); ?>

 <?php


 if (isset($_POST['anisave'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $stop = $_POST['stop'];
    $image_file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['image']['size'];

    if (empty($image_file) || empty($id)) {
        echo "Sorry, form is not complete yet!";
        header('Location: add.php');
    }
    else{
        $query_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anidata WHERE id = '$id'");
        $check = mysql_num_rows($query_id);

        if ($check > 0) {
            echo "Sorry, Anime ID not available";
            header('Location: add.php');
        }
        else{
            if ($type != "image/gif" && $type != "image/jpg" && $type != "image/jpeg" && $type != "image/png") {
                echo "Invalid image file, please use JPEG,JPG,PNG or GIF to upload the image."
                header('Location: add.php');
            }
            if ($size > 10000) {
                echo "Affordable file is under 10mB."
                header('Location: add.php');
            }
            else{
                $upload_directory = 'upload/';
                $temp = $upload_directory.$image_file;

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] , $temp)) {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO anidata VALUES ('$id', '$title', '$temp', '$genre', '$description','$start', '$stop')";
                    $query = mysql_query($sql)

                    if ($query) {
                        header('Location: view.php');
                    }
                    else{
                        echo mysql_query();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    echo "<p> Upload Failed, error code = " . $_FILES['location']['error']. "</p>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
 else{
    unset($_POST['anisave']);
 }


  ?>
```

Comment: if i am not wrong.. are you saving the path to image file in database?

Comment: yup, it should be like that. but i don't know why it's not saving any data i've add to the table.

Comment: is new row created with all values null or with some values present and some absent

Comment: sorry, all values are not null

Comment: try using `INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);`

Comment: What are the values that are NULL
??

Comment: Ty to change this ( $temp = $upload_directory.$image_file; ) to this ( $temp = $upload_directory.'.'.$image_file; )

Comment: i've tried both, and still not working.